# Coloring specific countries with geopandas

Tags: pandas, geopandas, graph-coloring

I want to map location of certain facilities on the African continent and I am able to do so using the code below. Now I want to color only specific countries (take Namibia as an example) to make another analysis more clear. Does anybode know a clean way of doing this? Thank you very much in advance.

Best,
Bram

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

data = pd.read_csv("Repair_yards_africa.csv")

base = world[world.continent == 'Africa'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

data['Coordinates'] = list(zip(data.lon, data.lat))
data['Coordinates'] = data['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
geodata = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='Coordinates')
geodata.plot(ax=base, color='red', markersize=11)
plt.ylabel('Lattitude')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
```

Comment: http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#choropleth-maps

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your comment. I have seen this page and tried out a few things including adding the cmap. I want to use the cmap only for specific countries, do you know a way of doing this? 'world.county == 'Namibia'' does not seem to be an object. Thank you

Comment: I have added this to it: http://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html

Comment: Got it, http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2017/classes/geopandas/mapping-with-geopandas/ This is a good link for anybody that is curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a "*clean way of coloring only specific countries (take Namibia as an example)*". Only relevant part of code is given.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from descartes import PolygonPatch

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

def plotCountryPatch( axes, country_name, fcolor ):
    # plot a country on the provided axes
    nami = world[world.name == country_name]
    namigm = nami.__geo_interface__['features']  # geopandas's geo_interface
    namig0 = {'type': namigm[0]['geometry']['type'], \
              'coordinates': namigm[0]['geometry']['coordinates']}
    axes.add_patch(PolygonPatch( namig0, fc=fcolor, ec="black", alpha=0.85, zorder=2 ))

# plot the whole world
#ax2 = world.plot( figsize=(8,4), edgecolor=u'gray', cmap='Set2' )

# or plot Africa continent
ax2 = world[world.continent == 'Africa'].plot(figsize=(8,8), edgecolor=u'gray', cmap='Pastel1')

# then plot some countries on top
plotCountryPatch(ax2, 'Namibia', 'red')
plotCountryPatch(ax2, 'Libya', 'green')

# the place to plot additional vector data (points, lines)

plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')

#ax2.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

**Edit**

Alternatively, the plot can be produced by this shorter version of code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
# from descartes import PolygonPatch

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# or plot Africa continent
ax2 = world[world.continent == 'Africa'].plot(figsize=(8,8), edgecolor=u'gray', cmap='Pastel1')

world[world.name == "Libya"].plot(edgecolor=u'gray', color='green', ax=ax2)
world[world.name == "Namibia"].plot(edgecolor=u'gray', color='red', ax=ax2)

# the place to plot additional vector data (points, lines)

plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')

#ax2.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Dear swatchai, this looks very eligant, thank you. I have used a bit less eligant way of adding a column with very low/high values to specify which countries to color in and using the cmap 'pastel1' to make a chloropeth map. That works as well! Thank you for your answer anyway.